# Error compiling in real device but not simulator iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, header, ios-simulator, device

I'm trying to compile a code using Reachability by Apple. Using an iPhone 5s on the simulator works.

But in iOS it's like some libraries are not included in the device.

It tells me that:

```
/Users/rebouhaymen/Desktop/Projets/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: note: in file included from /Users/rebouhaymen/Desktop/Projets/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike-Bridging-Header.h:6:
#import "Reachability.h"
        ^
/Users/rebouhaymen/Desktop/Projets/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike/Tools/Reachability/Reachability.h:49:9: error: 'SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h' file not found
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/rebouhaymen/Desktop/Projets/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike/UrBike-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h> should be present in the iOS SDK for device as well as simulator.  Please provide more context (eg: the command line for the failing compile)

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**. It seems I used 6.0 Xcode version instead 6.0.1. It works now.